# Conditional Gaussians in infinite dimensions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, hilbert-spaces, gaussian, bayesian-probability

I asked this over on cross validated, but thought it might also get an answer here:

The law of the conditional Gaussian distribution (the mean and covariance) are frequently mentioned to extend to the separable Hilbert spaced valued case, i.e., for $(X,Y)$,
$$
\mu_{X|Y=y} = \mu_X - C_{XY}C_{Y}^{-1}(\mu_Y - y)
$$
and
$$
C_{X|Y=y} = C_{X} - C_{XY}C_Y^{-1}C_{YX}
$$

I was trying to trace a proof for this in the separable Hilbert space case, and all the papers I found tended to point to *Linear Estimators and Measurable Linear Transformations on a Hilbert Space* by A. Mandelbaum (1984).  Digging through that paper, there's one a part of the proof I'm stumbling on:
[image]

I'm struggling with that first equality in (3.6), where the conditional expectation becomes the summation.  Thanks for any help.  Alternatively, if someone has a reference to another (better?) proof, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\Si\Sigma\newcommand\X{\mathbf X}$If $Y,X_1,\dots,X_n$ are jointly normal zero-mean (real-valued) random variables, [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions)
$$E(Y|X_1,\dots,X_n)=\Si_{12}\Si_{22}^{-1}\X,$$
where $\X:=[X_1,\dots,X_n]^\top$, $\Si_{22}:=Cov\,\X$ (the covariance matrix of $\X$), and $\Si_{12}:=Cov(Y,\X)=[Cov(Y,X_1),\dots,Cov(Y,X_n)]=[EYX_1,\dots,EYX_n]$.
If $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent, then $\Si_{22}$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $EX_1^2,\dots,EX_n^2$.

Applying these observations to $Y=(\theta,h)$ and $X_i=(X,e_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$, we get the equality in question.

Comment: This seems to assume that you know $(Y, X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ are jointly Gaussian; is that obvious?

Comment: @user2379888 : In Theorem 2 of Mandelbaum's paper, $\theta$ and $X$ are assumed to be jointly Gaussian (and zero-mean), which implies that $Y,X_1,\dots,X_n$ are jointly normal. Such an implication follows, in particular, from the third sentence of Section 3.3 of the paper.